# write to a file with a specific font size

Tags: bash, ascii-art

I want to write to a file in bash but I wan to use a specific font size. For example, I want to write to the file hello but with a font size of 30.

```
echo "Hello "
```

Also, is there another way to indent in bash when writing to a file besides using spaces like below?
echo "                  Hello"

Comment: What kind of file do you want to write to? `.txt` files and terminals don't support different font sizes, but `.html` files do

Comment: .txt files don't have font information. They contain text. `echo` simply outputs the text that it's told to echo, again without any font information. There is no way to embed font information into a text file.

Comment: Hi, yes its a text file Im writing too.

Answer (score 2):

As @thatotherguy commented, details like fonts are determined by the program reading the file, so it depends on what sort of file you're creating, and you'll typically use different tools to create different types of files. `echo` and other shell commands *just* work with text; the literal characters `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, and `o` are sent to the terminal, no size or font data goes along with it.

If you're trying to simply make big font in your terminal there are tricks, like [ASCII art text](https://www.shellhacks.com/create-ascii-text-banner-linux-command-line/) using [`figlet`](http://www.figlet.org/figlet-man.html):

```sh
$ figlet "Hello"
 _   _      _ _
| | | | ___| | | ___
| |_| |/ _ \ | |/ _ \
|  _  |  __/ | | (_) |
|_| |_|\___|_|_|\___/
```

And since you asked about indentation, notice that `figlet` supports centered text and other sorts of formatting:

```sh
figlet -c "Hello"
                              _   _      _ _
                             | | | | ___| | | ___
                             | |_| |/ _ \ | |/ _ \
                             |  _  |  __/ | | (_) |
                             |_| |_|\___|_|_|\___/
```

It is possible to make *some* changes to the text that gets displayed in your terminal (you've probably seen colored text before from some commands), but not fonts. You can use [`tput`](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termutils-2.0/html_mono/tput.html#SEC1) to modify the text you output, e.g. with colors or bold, but not size or font (which are configured by your terminal itself). Some examples of that in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/528928/12220), but `tput` is easier than figuring out all the `\e...` escape sequences they're talking about.

```sh
# it looks plain here, but if you run this in your shell it ought to be underlined
$ echo "$(tput smul)hello$(tput rmul)"
hello
```

---

If ASCII art or the color/font features most terminals support *isn't* what you're looking for, you'll need to share more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi dimo414, thank you for the info. Can I use figlet to write to a text file?

Comment: Sure, `figlet hello > foo.txt` will write ASCII art "hello" to a `foo.txt` file. It's just a bunch of characters that end up *looking* like large text.